# git diff --word-diff-regex - showing partial changes to camelcase names?

Tags: regex, git

Suppose I have changes within a camelcase name:

```
> git diff
diff --git a/file.cpp b/file.cpp
index c708fe5..76c127d 100644
--- a/file.cpp
+++ b/file.cpp
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-int CorrectHorseBatteryStaple(int a, int b, int c) {
+int CorrectZebraBatteryStaple(int a, int b, int c) {
     return 42;
 }
```

What pattern could I give to `--word-diff-regex` to show just which part of the camelcase name has changed?

This is the desired output:

```
> git diff --word-diff-regex=?????
diff --git a/file.cpp b/file.cpp
index c708fe5..76c127d 100644
--- a/file.cpp
+++ b/file.cpp
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
int Correct[-Horse-]{+Zebra+}BatteryStaple(int a, int b, int c) {
    return 42;
}
```

`--word-diff` splits on whitespace and includes too much: `[-CorrectHorseBatteryStaple(int-]{+CorrectZebraBatteryStaple(int+}`

`--word-diff-regex=.` treats each character separately and breaks words up: `[-Hors-]{+Z+}e{+bra+}`

Answer (score 1):

A pattern which splits terms by camelcase word and falls back to character-by-character:

`"([A-Z][a-z]*)|."`

This produces output which satisfies the example and also the problem I was solving when drafting the question:

```
> git diff --word-diff-regex="([A-Z][a-z]*)|."
diff --git a/file.cpp b/file.cpp
index c708fe5..76c127d 100644
--- a/file.cpp
+++ b/file.cpp
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
int Correct[-Horse-]{+Zebra+}BatteryStaple(int a, int b, int c) {
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: (This all looks a lot nicer in the terminal with `--color-diff` rather than monochrome [-removed-]{+added+} markup but I didn't feel like uploading a screenshot)